# Create three circles overlap each other

Tags: android, xml, view

I might be asking this question again but I didn't find any answers in Google

I need a view that shows

> Three Circles Overlapping each other

Left and right circles below middle circle

Each circle contain text view

[image: Thanks in advance]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml layout;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/circle1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Left circle"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/circle2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/circle1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circle1"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Middle circle"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/circle3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/circle2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circle2"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Right circle"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your drawable, insert bg_red.xml like this to make red circles;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <stroke android:color="#FF0000" android:width="5dip"/>
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Not overlap but you can modify the code as you wish

Comment: Thank I berkey.   But.  I need touch effect also

Comment: That circle goes back and come forward when I click it